# code igniter passing a library instance from one function to the next

Tags: php, codeigniter

From a code igniter function I am loading a library with arguments and it performs a bunch of things and initiliazes the library instance.
What is the right way to pass this instance to another function?

EDIT:

```
public function init()
{        
         //...
         $dataArr = array('directory' => $myDir, 'run' => TRUE);
     $this->load->library('lib_mylib', $dataArr);           


         // here I want to pass the lib_mylib instance to final();
                 // lib my lib has variables that gets set when loaded, I don't want to reloaded it again in the next function because it performs some operations that should only happen once. How can I get a handle of that initiliazed library inside final?
    }        

public function final($inputLibMyLib)
{           


}
```

Comment: some code would simplify the answer process

Comment: Show us your code, it's the only way anyone can help you here.

Comment: You shouldn't use `final` as a function name - that's a keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this code is in your Controller, just load the library in the Controller's constructor...

```
class Example extends CI_Controller {

    // load your Controller wide library here
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $dataArr = array('directory' => $myDir, 'run' => TRUE);
        $this->load->library('lib_mylib', $dataArr);
    }

    public funciton init()
    {
        $this->lib_mylib->function(); // is available
    }

    public funciton final()
    {
        $this->lib_mylib->function(); // is also available
    }

}
```

This constructor is called every time a function is requested.

***CLARIFICATION***

Doing this in the constructor is the best place because it guarantees that it is loaded before any following functions are.

However...

If you are calling functions sequentially the loaded library will hold over...

example

```
class Example extends CI_Controller {

    // load your Controller wide library here
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct()
    }

    public funciton init()
    {
        $dataArr = array('directory' => $myDir, 'run' => TRUE);
        $this->load->library('lib_mylib', $dataArr);

        $this->lib_mylib->function(); // is available

        // call next function
        $this->final();
    }

    public funciton final()
    {
        // is also available if final() is called from within init()
        $this->lib_mylib->function(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks but can't do this design for many complex reasons. How can I pass $this->lib_mylib as reference?  I can't do  final(&$this->lib_mylib)

Comment: Again, need to see more complete code to really help you... but it sounds like you are digging yourself into an overly complex design pattern that will haunt you.

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure to pass the library instance [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) to your function, and it should work.

Comment: All this does is make it so you can refer to the `session` library as `$this->my_session->function()` instead of `$this->session->function()`

Comment: Right, good point, I've updated the answer. I think all he needs to do is pass the library instance by reference. It's not a pattern I would recommend but it should work.

Comment: The reality is you are just stabbing in the dark, it's impossible to know what he is specifically asking.

Comment: Maybe you should read his question again then. What he's asking is actually pretty simple: `What is the right way to pass this instance to another function?` How many ways are there to pass an instance to another function?